# MySQL SubQuery doesn't seem to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table named "married" that consist of numerous fields, two fields in particular make-up the table primary-key. Those two field names are; "number", "date".

There are many records in duplicate that share the same "number" but have different "dates" associated.

I need to delete the record (row) within each pair, where the "number" is common between the two, but has the older "date" associated. But there is something goes wrong in the query.

```
delete number from married where number IN(select number from married)

and date <ANY( select date from married)
```

Comment: is `and date < ANY( select date from married)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete all but the most recent date for each number.  In MySQL, you are limited in the use of the table where the deletions are occurring in the rest of the query.  Fortunately, you can often get around this using a `join`.  I think this is what you want:

```
delete m
    from married m join
         (select number, max(date) as maxd
          from married
          group by number
         ) tokeep
         on m.number = tokeep.number and m.date < tokeep.maxd;
```